# Can I embed another users app in a html page on my website?

Tags: facebook

I have a non profit website dedicated to raising awareness about disabled dogs.  We also allow users to post urgent dog rescues needed (dogs that are in kill shelters that will be euthanised within next 48hrs).

There is a FB app at http://pretpardons.com that I would like to add to my site to allow visitors to see in real time which animals are in desperate need of adoption/rescue.

Is there any way that I can embed this fb app on my site?  I have the app id.

Many thanks for your help.

Best regards

Carl Hackman

Comment: That link you've posted is down :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. you can put frame another's fb app as facebook frames it.
However, fb app on your site won't have `signed_request`, so authentication will be done
by client side with fb javascript sdk. This means there may be some work to fb app's owners